# Does this show PyAudio is unusable with RaspberryPi's built-in audio?

Tags: python, audio, alsa

When using PyAudio with the RaspberryPi's built-in audio `snd_bcm2835`, we get this strange behaviour:

```
python test.py          
# ... after 10 or 15 seconds the sound is stuttering!
```

This problem doesn't exist when you use an external USB soundcard, a DAC, etc.

**How to solve this stuttering problem?**

---

It's very simple to reproduce the error. First you need PyAudio >= 0.2.8 (before, it doesn't support audio out via Callback function). Thus you can't `apt-get install pyaudio` (obsolete). Install PyAudio with:

```
sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get -y install python-dev portaudio19-dev
git clone http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git ; cd pyaudio ; sudo python setup.py install ; cd ..
```

You need to download [20seconds_sine.wav](http://gget.it/y9reof1e/20seconds_sine.wav). Then here is test.py [(download link here)](http://gget.it/b0rkli0o/test.py):

```
# taken from PyAudio example of playing wav / callback version
# http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#id4

import pyaudio
import wave
import time

wf = wave.open('20seconds_sine.wav', 'rb')

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    data = wf.readframes(frame_count)
    return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)

stream = p.open(format = pyaudio.paInt16, channels = 2, rate = 44100, frames_per_buffer = 2048, output = True, input = False, output_device_index = 0, stream_callback = callback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(0.1)

stream.stop_stream()

stream.close()

wf.close()

p.terminate()
```

Comment: Does `aplay` work?

Comment: @CL. Yes `aplay` works. It is strange that this code (example from the PyAudio doc: http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#example-callback-mode-audio-i-o) doesn't work. If you have a few seconds, could you try it on your RPi too?

Comment: Try `sudo nice --adjustment=-20 ./test.py`

Comment: I tried with nice `--adjustment=-20` and with higher buffer (8192 instead of 2048), it improves a bit, but the problem always appears (after 30 sec or 40 sec)